# Why Angular immediately invoke @HostListener when element is starting display in DOM?

Tags: angular

I'm writing a directive for close element when a user clicks outside of the host element. But I run into trouble because `@HostListener` is starting to call immediately when element displayed in the DOM. Maybe the problem isn't with `@HostListener`...

`@angular/core` version is 6.1.3
`browser` Google chrome 73.0

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appClickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    @Output() public appClickOutside = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(target: HTMLElement) {
        const isClickedInside = this.el.nativeElement.contains(target);

        if (!isClickedInside) {
            return this.appClickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'my-html-file.html'
})
export class Component {
  isOpened: boolean = false;
  open () {this.isOpened = true;}
  close () {this.isOpened = false;}
}
```

```html
<!-- my-html-file.html -->
<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, voluptatum!</p>

      <button (click)="open()">Opend my modal</button>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar"></div>
  </div>
</main>

<div class="modal" (appClickOutside)="close()">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2 class="modal-title">Hello world</h2>

    <button class="modal-close" (click)="close()">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, quidem.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The element should be in the DOM, but it appears and immediately disappears when I'm clicking on the button.

Comment: I hope that, my `Edit 1` explains your problem and `Edit 2` is an optimal solution for that. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ngez library which has an outside click directive:
https://ngez-platform.firebaseapp.com/#/core/outside-click

```
 <div 
    (ngezOutsideClick)="onOutsideClick()" 
    style="width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: aquamarine">
 </div>
```

Comment: Hmm... use library for trivial task like this, is not suitable.

Comment: @haacki47, it's not like you're importing the entire library. It'll all still be dropped when you build, but anyway, you can look at the source code.

Comment: I've checked the source code of the library and found very interesting solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the button it's already outside of the div with MODAL, so it triggers the directive and the div remains closed. To remedy that, put the directive on a wrapper div. It will contain the button and the modal div.
Something like this :

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:100px" (appClickOutside)="close()">

  <button (click)="open()">open modal </button>
  <div style="position:relative;width:300px;border:1px solid black" *ngIf="isOpened">MODAL</div>

</div>
```

I added some styling to show the position and div limites.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cetajm).

Comment: You absolutely right, but it will not work in my case, because i need to open menu via button which is separately placed in the markup.

Comment: If the both (the button and the modal) are in the same component, you still can wrap the whole thing. Just put the wrapper div at the top

Comment: @Vega that would defeat the whole purpose; the modal should close when you click out of the modal. Not only when you click out of a huge div containing the modal and plenty of other stuff.

Comment: @Vega I made some changes in my question, now you can see the whole picture of the markup.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: See **Edit 2**

Here is what happens:

1. First the `open()` method of `Component` class gets called.
2. Then the `<div (appClickOutside)="close()"....>` element gets activated and rendered.
3. Immediately afterwards, since the `document.click` event was registered due to previous click and still in progress, the `onClick()` method inside the `ClickOutsideDirective` gets called. `isClickedInside` is evaluated as `falsy`, since you know, the activated `div` element wasn't the target element at this time
4. `if (!isClickedInside)` then becomes `truty`, thus the `appClickOutside` event is emitted, which will cause the `close()` callback to be called.

Here is an example, that demonstrates what's going on (Please open your developer console to see the logs): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nci8or

However, you can easily work around this problem by wrapping `this.isOpened = true;` with `setTimeout`, which looks like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {this.isOpened = true; });
```

P.S. If no delay time is specified, `setTimeout()` is simply executed when the stack is unwound.

---

**Edit**: The title of your question actually sums up the trouble you are having pretty well, and I didn't address it directly, sorry about that.

Well, at least in the third step, you can guess what happens behind the scenes. A click event is triggered, **and before it bubbles further upwards till the `document` element, the `<div>` element is activated and rendered. Meanwhile, the target element is the button element, but that `click` event is also registered for `document` element too - even it's not reached the `document` element yet**. The rest simply describes what happens next. Here is more about event bubbling and capturing: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

---

**Edit 2**: The ideal solution would be the following:

Template: Pass the `MouseEvent` to the method

```html
<button (click)="open($event)">open modal</button>
```

Component: Prevent the event from bubbling up

```js
open($event: MouseEvent) { 
  $event.stopPropagation();
  this.isOpened = true; 
}
```

Comment: Solution with stopPropagation is more likely :) Thank you for detail explanation.